# Java jdk 1.8.0_321 SNI getting overwritten by hostname

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, httpsurlconnection, sslsocketfactory

One of the server my client application connects to is going to require SNI sent in requests. They are going to host multiple apps on same host and port.

My app Jdk version - 1.8.0_321
I updated my code to add SNI through SSLSocketFactory. Now I am facing an interesting problem.

Assume server side is as below.
Host - abc.com (1.1.1.1)
Port - 8443
Server1 - domain1.com
Server2 - domain2.com

1. If I send 1.1.1.1 as url and add domain1.com/domain2.com as SNIServerName, server is recieving the correct domain name
2. If I send abc.com as url and add domain1.com/domain2.com as SNIServerName, the ssl debug logs shows that it is getting overwritten with abc.com and send. Even server side logs show abc.com

Note : for scenario #2, there is an additional log line which says
"The previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=domain2.com) was replaced with (type=host_name (0), value=abc.com)

What does this mean?
I am going in circles after reading some related topics.